# How to get the minimum transconductance of a BJT ce amplifier?

Tags: circuit-analysis, amplifier, bjt, small-signal

[image]

We are being asked to bias a ce ampilifier circuit above to a gain of 15. It is given that the DC supply voltage is 10 V and a Vce,sat = 0.3V. Assuming that ro >> Rl >> Rload (on Vout when its connected), what should be the minimum transconductance?

Comment: Are you allowed to modify that schematic? For example, can you add a resistor to it? Because it is NOT possible to establish a manageable voltage gain of 15 with the circuit you show. Can't be done.

Comment: ...perhaps with C2=1pF ?

Comment: A BJT CE amplifier (as per what you show) doesn't have transconductance; it has gain. A BJT (on its own) has transconductance. Hence your question is confusing.

Comment: Can be done ... select a 2N3055 as the transistor and choose an appropriate value of Ic from its datasheet.